# Find-Item -Index Get latest version

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I am looking for a master index query that will return the latest version of any item. In the solr index there is a field call `_latestversion`. But when I add that to my query, I get the error

> Find-Item : No property or field '_latestversion' exists in type 'SearchResultItem'

Here is my query

```
$items = Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index -Where '(TemplateId=@0 Or TemplateId=@1) And Path.Contains(@2) And _latestversion=true' -WhereValues $clubTemplateId, $wogTemplateId, $roothPath | Initialize-Item
```

I could use a Get-Item for each result, but that is overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using SPE 6.0 this might work for you. Introduced with this [issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1120).

```powershell
class ExtendedSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
   [Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexField("_latestversion")]
   [bool]$IsLatestVersion
}

$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Where = "IsLatestVersion == @0"
    WhereValues = $true
    QueryType = [ExtendedSearchResultItem]
}

Find-Item @props -First 10
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome Mike.

Comment: @Michael has SPE 6.0 released? It's not available in the marketplace. Can you please provide a link to download it?

Comment: Yes it has been released on GitHub. Please view the release page for more details.  https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `_latestVersion` with Find-Item command then you will need to use `-Criteria` instead of `-Where` because `-Where` uses `SearchResultItem` class to map the properties whereas `-Criteria` work directly against Solr fields.

**Example -**

```
$clubTemplateId = New-Object Sitecore.Data.ID::new("{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}")  
$wogTemplateId = New-Object Sitecore.Data.ID::new("{716FD1F8-FB35-40FA-A144-B0A6BA96E967}") 

$roothPath = "/sitecore/content"    

$idHelper = New-Object Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper

$criteria = @(
                @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = $roothPath},
                @{Filter = "ContainsAny"; Field = "_template"; Value = [string[]]@($idHelper::NormalizeGuid($clubTemplateId), $idHelper::NormalizeGuid($wogTemplateId))},
                @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_latestversion"; Value = "1"}
            )

$items =Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index -Criteria $criteria | Initialize-Item

Write-Host $items.Length
```